# Parse JSCH response to list

Tags: groovy, soapui, jsch

I'm trying to parse the response from JSCH (it was a grep cmd with multiple lines as a response) and i'm trying to add each line to a list (for later processing). I'm using the shell channel if that means anything. Here's the function:

```
static public List<String> waitForPrompt(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, String prompt) throws Exception {
    int retries = 700
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>()
    for (int x = 1; x < retries; x++) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)
        String responseString = outputStream.toString()
        responseString.eachLine { line ->
            lines.add(line.replaceAll("(\\x9B|\\x1B\\[)[0-?]*[ -\\/]*[@-~]", ""))
        }
        if (lines.find { it.contains(prompt) }) {
            return lines
        }
        outputStream.reset()
    }
    throw new Exception("Prompt failed to show after specified timeout")
}
```

I do see both entries, but the list that's created only has one item (the entire response ;( ). Why?

Comment: Are you using some sort of special API? No class in the JRE has an `eachLine` method that I can see, especially not `String`. The JRE would require `String responseString = new String(outputStream.getBytes());`

Comment: @g00se this is Groovy, which adds some "magical" methods to existing classes. About needing to use `new String(...)`: `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()` is implemented to do just that (but a bit more efficiently).

Comment: My apologies, I've removed java from the tags

Comment: *@g00se this is Groovy* Thank you. If was beginning to worry if I'd entered some parallel universe. The code was getting weirder the more I read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, dont use the shell, use exec channel. I stopped using the prompt instead I'm doing this:

```
private String getChannelOutput(Channel channel, InputStream in) throws IOException{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = ""
    while(!channel.isClosed()){
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024)
            if (i < 0) {
                log.info('found no response')
                break;
            }
            strBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, i))
            Thread.sleep(100)
        }
    }
    return strBuilder.toString()        
}
```